# How do I filter a Observable on a property that is an Observable?

Tags: ios, swift3, rx-swift

The thing is that I have a Protocol that contains properties I want to sort on when they are available. As I'm trying to making everything ultra Reactive.

```
protocol DeviceConnectionProtocol {
...
    var id : Observable<String> { get }
...
}
```

And I'm in a situation where I want to find the last device I was connected to regardless of url/name/etc changed.

```
  class DeviceFinder {

    let rx_DeviceList = Variable([DeviceConnectionProtocol]())
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    init() {
        SMOIPConnection.FindDevices().subscribe(onNext : { smoip in
            self.rx_DeviceList.value.append(smoip)
        }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

        MockDevice.FindDevices().subscribe(onNext : { mock in
            self.rx_DeviceList.value.append(mock)
        }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

    }

}
```

...

This is the function I have so far for sorting. But it is not workable as device.id.map returns a Observable not a Bool that is needed for a filter operation

```
struct LastConnectedDevice {

    private static let lastConnectedKeyForID = "lastConnected"

    static func get() -> Observable<DeviceConnectionProtocol>{
    let lastID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: lastConnectedKeyForID)
       return DeviceFinder().rx_DeviceList.asObservable().flatMap{list in
            return Observable.from(list)
            }.filter { (device : DeviceConnectionProtocol) -> Bool in
                return device.id.map{ id in
                    return id == lastID
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Diagnosis

From how I understood your problem, you're having difficulty performing the filter operation because the attribute is an `Observable<Int>` instead of an `Int`. That means you can't just check the IDs with an equal operator, because you [need to get out of the Rx monad](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#life-happens).

### Staying on the Rx Monad

For a more elegant FRP solution:

1. Define your device observable.
2. Define your device ID observable.
3. [Zip](http://rxmarbles.com/#zip) them together.
4. [Filter](http://rxmarbles.com/#filter) by [checking](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html) the last device ID.
5. Return to the data type that you want (`DeviceConnectionProtocol`).
6. Execute necessary code using the last device.

Here's the RxSwift code. Some of my class definitions can be seen in the code block below this one.

```
// Observable<DeviceConnectionProtocol>
let devices = rx_DeviceList
    .asObservable()
    .flatMap { array in Observable.from(array) } 

// Observable<Int>
let deviceIDs = devices
    .flatMap { device in device.id } 

Observable.zip(devices, deviceIDs) { $0 } 

    // data type of (DeviceConnectionProtocol, Int)
    .filter { $0.1 == lastID }
    .map { $0.0 }
    .subscribe(onNext: lastDeviceSelected)
```

*Monad is simply a way of saying paradigm, way of processing, or thinking. You can always exit the RxMonad which means leaving the data streams and returning to imperative code. This is what programmers are more used to.*

---

### Simple way to exit the Rx Monad

Here's a (somewhat messy) solution. TL;DR go to the **How to exit the RxMonad synchronously** section.

```
import RxSwift

protocol DeviceConnectionProtocol {
    var id : Observable<String> { get }
}


class Person : DeviceConnectionProtocol {
    var myName: String! = nil

    init(name: String) {
        self.myName = name
    }

    var id: Observable<String> {
        return Observable.create { [unowned self] obx in
            obx.onNext(self.myName)
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
let rx_DeviceList = Variable([DeviceConnectionProtocol]())
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

let lastID = "Hillary"

func lastDeviceSelected(device: DeviceConnectionProtocol) {
    if let person = device as? Person {
        print(person.myName + " was found!")
    }
}

rx_DeviceList
    .asObservable()
    .flatMap { array in Observable.from(array) }
    .filter{ (device: DeviceConnectionProtocol) -> Bool in

        // How to exit the RxMonad synchronously

        // Have a result variable
        var currentID = ""

        // Subscribe on the observable on the default schedulers (main thread) and assign result
        device.id.subscribe(onNext: { (id: String) in currentID = id })

        // Return result
        return lastID == currentID
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: lastDeviceSelected)

rx_DeviceList.value = [Person(name: "Donald"), Person(name: "Goofy"), Person(name: "Hillary")]
```

Result:

```
Hillary was found!
```

Note that sequences that end (e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5]`) are able to use the `takeLast` operator but for some reason, your case is different and it doesn't work.

### Reference and notes

1. Here's a [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/darrensapalo/faf4307c84deaf0c05d02c17de7e118b) if you want to the whole code which works on the Rx Playground.
2. The `zip` operator visualized on [RxMarbles](http://rxmarbles.com/#zip).
3. The `zip` operator [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html).
4. The `filter` operator visualized on [RxMarbles](http://rxmarbles.com/#filter).
5. The `filter` operator [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html).
6. This is a Swift 3 solution.

Comment: I have a problem with both solutions. The Staying in the monad : You are expecting devices and deviceIDs to be updated synchronized when in reality there are no guarantees they are. On the way to exit monad. you are comparing lastID == currentID but there is again no guarantee that device.id.subscribe(onNext: { (id: String) in currentID = id }) has finished executing

Comment: Hi Daniel Poulsen, i hope that [this gist](https://gist.github.com/darrensapalo/6f2bb5946d97cf87033b75aac6b98a43) can explain effectively how the solution posted above addresses those concerns. tl;dr Observable.zip ensures the pairs are synchronized, and `subscribe` method runs on the current thread the observable was created in, which is in most cases the main thread, making it synchronous. Let me know if I misunderstood or got something wrong.